# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[REAEventDispatcher setBridge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-reanimated

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[REAEventDispatcher setBridge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282708dc0'

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically from the reanimated package.

Just update the reanimated to the latest.

```
 npm i react-native-reanimated@latest
```

Then do pod install.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue in my Lerna monorepo. I had two projects using reanimted but had different react-native version.

**RCA:**
All modules were hoisted except react-native because versions were different. As reanimated library was hoisted and react-native wasn't it was throwing this exception.

**Solution:**
I updated both project with same react-native version. I am not facing this issue now. Both projects working fine with reanimated.